# Android Room Database: How to properly select a 'tableName' in the DAO @Query?

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to select the tableName set in the @Entity annotation within the @Query method in the Dao interface, but it won't recognize tableName and id. Am I missing something?

**Cannot resolve symbol 'photo_table'**

**Cannot resolve symbol 'id'**

```
//Entity file
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "photo_table")
public class Photo {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;

    public int photoItem;

    public String title;

    public String description;
}

// Dao Interface
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface PhotoDao {
    @Insert
    void Insert(Photo photo);
    @Update
    void Update(Photo photo);
    @Delete
    void Delete(Photo photo);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM photo_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    LiveData<List<Photo>> getAllPhotos();
}
```

Comment: Did you add this table after the database was already created once? If so you will need to update the database version number for the changes to take place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have forgotten add your entity class to required annotation in your abstract class extends **RoomDatabase**.

```
@Database(entities = {Photo.class}, version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase { 
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved the issue, I just added the braces around that expression and it worked.